# How to determine correct files and blocks to be edited in Magento2?

Tags: magento2

this might seem like a strange question but I am learning Magento 2 at the moment and could use some guidance when it comes to figuring out an easier way than guessing to determine what are the correct files and blocks to edit. Let me demonstrate what I mean.

Say I want to edit template and layout of the customer review section of the customer account page.

[image: review section]

I figured out after a while of searching around that `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/customer/list.html` was the correct template file I need to override, and I turned out to be correct, but it was kind of a lucky guess. There were a lot of other files around there that it seemed it could also possibly be.

Alright, we are getting somewhere. Now I need to change the layout, so which layout file do I need to edit? I tried `vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/review_customer_list.xml` but this doesn't seem to be the correct one. Actually, there seems to be about 4/5 files in this same folder it could potentially be, and I don't seem to have any context to go off other than vague file names. Is trial and error, and guessing what we rely on to figure this out or is there a much easier way to determine this. I know this might be a really stupid, newbie question but I'm a little confused.

Additionally, when testing if this is the correct file I am trying to remove the pager at the bottom right and move the toolbar under the page title. How do I know what the correct names of these blocks are? I tried:

```
<move element="products.reviews.toolbar" destination="column.main" after="page.title"/>
<referenceBlock name="pager" remove="true" />
```

which didn't work, but I am also kind of just guessing the names of these blocks if I am honest. I have no idea if this is what these blocks are called.

Are there any easy ways to determine all these things instead of guessing? ID's in the DOM or something like this that reveal the names of the blocks/layouts I need to edit? Something like this?

Thanks for the help